# Black screen after packaging to APK

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-js

i create a simple memory game with the last version of cocos code IDE(**v1.2.0**) and last version of cocos2d-JS(**v3.3**) and it work fine on the WEB and also work well when i debug it to an android simulator(BlueStack) and my android device, **BUT** when i have to debug it on BlueStack the following error appear in the IDE consol: `JS: /data/data/org.cocos2dx.PrebuiltRuntimeJs/files/debugruntime/script/jsb_create_apis.js:910:Error: js_cocos2dx_LabelTTF_create : wrong number of arguments` so i delete all argument for `cc.LabelTTF.create` except `text, fontName, fontSize` to debug the game correctly.
[image]
<sub>(source: [cocos2d-x.org](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/uploads/default/_optimized/130/6b2/7a73805d54_543x500.PNG))</sub>

**i get this alert box when i want to package to APK.(i clicked YES)**
[image]
<sub>(source: [cocos2d-x.org](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/uploads/default/8671/042ae9701d86d3b3.PNG))</sub>

**Now,** after i get the APK file (result of package the game to apk), i get a black screen that show only the FPS on both BlueStack and my android device.
**Note** that when i package the default HelloWolrd project it works **correctly** without this problem.
[image]
<sub>(source: [cocos2d-x.org](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/uploads/default/_optimized/d49/58a/93fabf664b_690x444.PNG))</sub>

i use the last version of ant(**v1.9.4**) and NDK **r9d**

also when i debug the apk file generated form package to apk option i just got this line in the console:

```
Start LaunchActivity org.example.concentration/org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity
```

and the black screen with the FPS appear on the emulator and android device. so i can't see what happen.

i also check the content of build-cfg.json file and this why i get.

```
{
    "ndk_module_path" :[
        "../../js-bindings",
        "../../js-bindings/cocos2d-x",
        "../../js-bindings/cocos2d-x/cocos",
        "../../js-bindings/cocos2d-x/external"
    ],
    "copy_resources": [
        {
            "from": "../../../src",
            "to": "src"
        },
        {
            "from": "../../../res",
            "to": "res"
        },
        {
            "from": "../../../main.js",
            "to": ""
        }
    ],
    "must_copy_resources": [
        {
            "from": "../../js-bindings/bindings/script",
            "to": "script"
        },
        {
            "from": "../../../config.json",
            "to": ""
        },
        {
            "from": "../../../project.json",
            "to": ""
        } 
    ]
}
```

and when i unpacked the apk file i found the resources too.
[image]
<sub>(source: [cocos2d-x.org](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/uploads/default/8668/ace5076aa5c53b64.PNG))</sub>

the pictures are in the assets folder.

this is exactly the same structure as the default Hello World simple project created by cocos IDE.
(the only difference is that the default project work after packaging and my game doesn't!)

How can i solve this problem?

thanks in advance.